# How to turn a Type instance into a generic type argument

Tags: c#, generics, types, generic-type-argument

I basically have something like this:

```
void Foo(Type ty)
{
    var result = serializer.Deserialize<ty>(inputContent);
}

Foo(typeof(Person));
```

The `Deserialize<ty>` doesn't work because it expects `Deserialize<Person>` instead. How do I work around this?

I'd also like to understand how generics work and why it won't accept `ty` which is `typeof(Person)`.

EDIT: I ought to have mentioned that this is a contrived example. I cannot actually change the signature of the function because it implements an interface.

EDIT: serializer is a JavascriptSerializer and implemented as an action filter here. It is called thusly:

```
[JsonFilter(Param="test", JsonDataType=typeof(Person))]
```

### Solution

Based on Marc and Anton's answers:

```
var result = typeof(JavaScriptSerializer).GetMethod("Deserialize")
                 .MakeGenericMethod(JsonDataType)
                 .Invoke(serializer, new object[] { inputContent });
```

Comment: Surely it would be easier to change the interface (or add a new overload of Foo) than to look for a work round when the correct code is so simple?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `ty` is known at compile-time, why don't just

```
void Foo<T>()
{
    var result = serializer.Deserialize<T>(inputContext);
}
```

Otherwise,

```
MethodInfo genericDeserializeMethod = serializer.GetType().GetMethod("Deserialize");
MethodInfo closedDeserializeMethod = genericDeserializeMethod.MakeGenericMethod(ty);
closedDeserializeMethod.Invoke(serializer, new object[] { inputContext });
```

Answer (score 7):

Which serializer is that? If you only know the `Type` at runtime (not compile time), and it doesn't have a non-generic API, then you might have to use `MakeGenericMethod`:

```
void Foo(Type ty)
{
    object result = typeof(ContainingClass).GetMethod("Bar").
        .MakeGenericMethod(ty).Invoke(null, new object[] {inputContent});
}
public static T Bar<T>(SomeType inputContent) {
    return serializer.Deserialize<T>(inputContent);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what ContainingClass is here and why pass in "Bar"?

Comment: ContainingClass is the class that has the Bar method, and "Bar" is used to **find** the Bar method by name. You could also (per Anton's answer) go straight to the "Serialize" method on the serializer.

Comment: Got it now. This works: var result = typeof(JavaScriptSerializer).GetMethod("Deserialize")                   .MakeGenericMethod(JsonDataType).Invoke(serializer, new object[] { inputContent });  calling Invoke(null, ...) throws a  TargetException ("non-static method required")

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
void Foo<T>(){ var result = serializer.Deserialize<T>(inputContent); }
```

With the following call

```
Foo<Person>();
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, just do this:

```
void Foo<ty>()
{
    var result = serializer.Deserialize<ty>(inputContent);
}

Foo<Person>();
```

Otherwise, you need to call the generic method late-bound, since you have to get the correct generic method for it first (it is not known at compile time). Have a look at the [MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod(VS.95).aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

Like Lucero said,

```
void Foo<ty>()
{
    var result = serializer.Deserialize<ty>(inputContent);
}

Foo<Person>();
```

typeof(Person) is not the same thing as Person. Person is a compile-time type, whereas typeof(Person) is an expression that *returns a Type instance representing the runtime type information of Person*.